# Setting a scanner object to null

Tags: java, methods, null, java.util.scanner, bluej

When I try to compile this code it works well, but when I want to test the methods, the first method works well but the second method throws an exception error pointer equal to null, but if I change `scanner = null;` to `scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` it works fine so how can I solve this problem without creating a new scanner each time

```
public class Sca extends input
{

    private Scanner scanner;
    private String userInput;

    public ArrayShoppingList11()
    {
        super();
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    }


   protected  void addCar()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Car to be added");
         userInput = scanner.nextLine(); 
        super.add(userInput);
        setScanner();

    }

    protected int getPosition()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the car");
         userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        int z = super.indexOf(userInput);
        System.out.println("The position of " + userInput + "is: " + z);  // used for the main class Testing purposes 
         setScanner();
        return z;
    }
       private void setScanner()
    {
        if(scanner != null)
        {
            scanner = null;
        }

    }
}
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayShoppingList1 a = new ArrayShoppingList1();



    a .printList();
    a.addCar();  
    a .getPosition();// returning the position of an item using name of the item


    a .checkEmpty();
    a.additem();
    a .printList();
    a .removeItem();// removing the item using the index of the item 
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you setting the scanner to null?

Comment: because when I read userInput tiwce , it will just take th old input from the user and assgin it to the scanner

Comment: @mohamedghassar: you have no main method to show us how you're testing this, nor do you have the code for input class the one this one is extending. It's hard to test your code to see why you need this kludge. I fear that you're fixing the wrong error.

Comment: I ve added the test class when I add the second car It just add it by it self

Comment: You um, might want to change name of your class from "Sca"...?

Comment: And your code compiles?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable to null doesn't get rid of the resources used. What you need to do is to *close* the Scanner when you're done using it via:

```
myScanner.close();
```

This will allow that any resources used by this object are released and can be used again. If you do this, and if you declare it in the most local scope possible, there's no need to null the variable.

---

As for your actual question, note that you have no main method to show us how you're testing this, nor do you have the code for input class the one this one is extending. It's hard to test your code to see why you need this kludge. I fear that you're fixing the wrong error.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each of your methods, you call `setScanner`. The `setScanner` method changes the class's scanner object to `null`, which means that next time you call a method you are in fact using a null scanner.

Just don't call `setScanner` at the end of your methods; the same scanner object can be used multiple times without any issues.